# stable-diffusion-webui doesnt start

Tags: python, pip, stable-diffusion

I installed everything, but I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wcwidth'`, even though I install 'wcwidth' via pip, it still gives the same error

I installed wcwidth I expected it to work but it didn't

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have installed two or more python versions,go to site-packages remove all the wcwidth ,then pip3 uninstall wcwidth
then pip3 install wcwidth
or pip3 install wcwidth --user
may it help